# Images rotate along y axis

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, uiimage, axis

[image]

How can let the images rotate along y axis?
I try to use this code,but it just rotate along image's y axis.

```
imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(imageView.layer.transform, CATransform3DMakeRotation(180,0.0,1.0,0.0));
```

Anybody can solve my question?many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate first (by half of image width) and then rotate.

Comment: do not quite  understand what you mean,can you provide some code?

Comment: It would be something like `CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DMakeTranslation(width/2,0,0), 90, 0, 1, 0), -width/2, 0, 0)`. Basically you need to move origin location, rotate and then move back.